# Django Project with Multiple Apps on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, architecture

A newbie question:

I've been able to deploy a few simple Django apps on Heroku very easily.

However, now I am tackling a much larger project that consists of several apps (all Django and all with restricted access) under one Django project that will all use one central Heroku PostgreSQL db.  The catch, of course,  is that Heroku would deploy this as just one big Heroku app thus preventing one from taking advantage of scaling dynos up and down per Django app (some apps will have much greater usage than others).

I've spent a few days researching this and it looks like I will have to build a REST api to allow each app to interact (they will need to) and then deploy them as separate Heroku apps i.e. each as its own Django project.  There is obviously quite a bit of overhead and admin (managing multiple settings etc.) to develop and maintain this api but I can't see another way if I need to scale up and down individual apps.

Before I embark on this, I'd be most interested in hearing any alternative suggestions (bearing in mind that we really like Heroku and we really need to scale the individual dynos!).  There does not seem to be much documentation on the web on this topic but one would think it a fairly common scenario.

Answer (score 1):

What's the disadvantage of scaling the entire project? It doesn't matter if the dyno serves one app or many: it's the number of requests overall that counts. An app isn't really a discrete thing in Django terms, it's just a collection of models and views, and it doesn't make much sense to try and separate them. Separate services connected by REST are a really great thing - my own projects often work like that - but they're not required, and there's no point rewriting your code that way unless you need to.